if $f,g$ are continuous and increasing, $\exists! (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $u+f(u-v)=v+g(v-u)=0$
I'm going in circles to show the unicity
$h: u \mapsto u + f(u - v)$ is strictly increasing with v fixed and by IVT $\exists! u \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(u)=0$  (easy to show)
Same is true with $d: u \mapsto v + g(v - u)$ with $u \in \mathbb{R}$ fixed
To my mind, the unicity comes from monotony and injectiv functions, but I struggle to show
it.
If I choose $u$, then $v$ has to be chosen, but $u$ too and here's my circle...
I tried to suppose that there exist 2 couples $(u,v)$ that are solutions and find a contradiction, but it didn't work.
Do you have any advice?

Consider the functions
$$h_1 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \quad h_1(x) := x + f(x)$$
and
$$h_2 : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \quad h_2(x) := g(-x).$$
Then $h_1$ is increasing and $h_2$ is decreasing, so they can intersect at most once, say at $x_0$. If you plug $x := u-v$ into $h_1(x) = h_2(x)$, you get
$$u-v + f(u-v) = g(v-u).$$
That is, in order for your first equation to be satisfied, we must necessarily have $u-v = x_0$. But this means $u = -f(x_0)$ and $v = -g(-x_0)$, hence they are unique.

You suppose that they intersect, but it isn't necessary the case to my opinion...

@Dlouna.J You only asked for uniqueness. In any case, it is easy to see that $h_1$ is bijective and therefore by the intermediate value theorem $h_1$ and $h_2$ have to intersect.

As you said, for every $u\in \mathbb R$ there exist exactly one $v$ such that $v+g(v-u)=0$ so we can define function $\varphi :\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ by formula $\varphi (u)=v$ if and only if $v+g(v-u)=0$. Now we have to seek only solutions in form $(u, \varphi(u))$. Our function $\varphi$ is increasing and from that we can conclude that $u\to u-\varphi (u)$ is also increasing. Indeed if we set $u_1<u_2$ we have:
$$\varphi (u_1)<\varphi(u_2) $$
$$ g(\varphi(u_1)-u_1)= -\varphi(u_1)>-\varphi(u_2)=g(\varphi(u_2)-u_2)$$
$$\varphi(u_1)-u_1>\varphi(u_2)-u_2 $$
$$ u_1-\varphi(u_1)<u_2-\varphi(u_2)$$
But that means $u+f(u-\varphi(u))=0$ have exactly one solution since LHS is sum of two increasing functions.

I do not understand how you can define such a function $φ$, how do you know that you can isolate $v$?

If we fix $u \in \mathbb R$ we know that equation $v+g(v-u)=0$ has unique solution (beacause LHS is increasing and continuous) which we can set to be value of $\varphi$ for argument $u$. Repeating this process for all $u \in \mathbb R$ we get full definition of $\varphi$.

Hmmm okay I understood, Thanks a lot

How do you show that $\varphi$ is decreasing?

Function $\varphi $ is increasing.  If you take $u_1<u_2$ and let $v_1=\varphi (u_1), v_2=\varphi (u_2)$ you have $v_1+g(v_1-u_2)<v_1+g(v_1-u_1)=0=v_2+g(v_2-u_2)$ but because function $x\to x+g(x-u_2)$ is increasing then must follow that $v_1<v_2$
